# Question about remove_action() in WooCommerce and 3rd Party Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

First, I apologize for a newb question, but alas, I'm learning.

I'm a little stuck here and would love some guidance. I'm new to WordPress theme customization, but have had some experience with `add_action()`. I have a gift card plugin that injects the gift card code after the Terms & Conditions. I want to move it directly below the payment information.

[image]

Using Simply Show Hooks, I've identified the hook that I want to remove using `remove_action()`:

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', ' PW_Gift_Cards_Redeeming –> woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 10  );`

See the attached screenshot of the hook: [image]

However, this method is not working at all. Any guidance on how to remove this? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', array('PW_Gift_Cards_Redeeming', 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit'), 10  );
```

Try like this

Comment: hmm..good idea, I tried it, but It's not working on my end. Any other ideas? It's a third-party plugin, obviously.